# debian завис на экране загрузки gnome display manager

Tags: linux, debian, amd

люди!
Установил десятую debian. Установка прошла хорошо. При первой же загрузки ОС, она встала на загрузке gnome display manager. 
Гугл ничего не знает, кроме как обновить биос, но на оф сайте асрок пишут это: *ASRock do NOT recommend updating this BIOS if Pinnacle, Raven, Summit or Bristol Ridge CPU is being used on your system.
У меня процессор как раз на bristol ridge: AMD a8 9600
не знаю насколько опасно обновлять биос, я не рискнул.
есть идеи как исправить эту проблему? Дело по ходу в видеокарте amd. Отдельной видеокарты тоже нет.
еще в загрузке показывается такая ошибка: firmware failed to load rtl_nic/rtl8168h-2.fw

Answer (score 1):

1) грузись в `nomodeset noapic nolapic` будет графика тормозить, но отрисуется - переключись в консольку

2) качай обновление на биос материнки и обнови, но если не уверен, то оставь этот пункт на потом - нужно обновить биос если на экране будут появляться артефакты и всякие цветные квадраты или дергаться картинка, не тормозит, а именно дергается.

3) качай сборку дров https://github.com/q3aql/drivers-linux-firmware или мучайся с установщиком от АМД

4) понадобится rsync, если интерет не завелся скачай отдельно https://packages.debian.org/buster/amd64/rsync/download

5) добавь бакпорт и non-free в репозитории /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main contrib non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib non-free
```

6) `apt update && apt -t buster-backports upgrade && apt install firmware-realtek rsync`

это в основном для того чтоб получить пятое ядро.

7) установи сборку фирмвари `dpkg -i drivers-linux-firmware_20200206-1_all.deb`

8) перезагрузись без параметров граба.

9) если будет черный экран и изображение пропало полностью,
попробуй загрузиться с параметрами `amdgpu.dc=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1`
такая фигня на гигабайтах с ВГА разъемом без разъема hdmi

Исправь строчку `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="amdgpu.dc=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1"` в /etc/default/grub если заработает

```
update-grub
```

Эти танцы уже делаю за 15 минут) если страшно, то попробуй Убунту - там дрова в комплекте обычно... но я ей не пользовался давно - не знаю как там с поддержкой всего этого

Comment: Спасибо! Последовал вашему второму совету) убунту работает вообще без проблем!)

Answer (score 0):

на raisen 5 похожая проблема,

1. обновление матери можно делать без рабочей ос загружаешься в биос и там обновляешься, не всем и не всегда к сожалению помогает

2 на убунте ноут заработал но при нагрузке все вешалось напрочь и уже не востанавливалось.

3. под дебианом к сожалению у меня гном не подавал прищнаков жизни а мучится времени не было.
4. добавление в конфиг груба доп настроек не помогало.
5. на манджаро заработало после небольших настроек [https://forum.manjaro.org/t/manjaro-with-4-19-kernel-and-ryzen-5-2500u-apu/66433][1] 
   работает стабильно

проблема с микрокодом амд как понимаю

Comment: да, слишком много возни. В итого просто установил убунту

Answer (score 0):

Я мало понимаю в линуксе, и столкнулся с этой проблемой в Debian 11.3. Сисиема при загрузке вдруг стала останавливаться на строке display manager, или на следующей, не буду уточнять. Важно, как я удачно нашел решение. Я пришел к выводу, что последняя задача, которая выполнялась, это закачка фильма. Комп был выключен, а я не посмотрел его состояние, что зря, так как свободного места осталось "0", и при очередной загрузке система просто не смогла развернуться. Печально, такое бывало только в старинных версиях винды, и от последнего Debian я этого не ожидал. Я запустил live CD, вытащил с жесткого диска несколько медиафайлов,перезапустил комп, и всё заработало!